# disjunction of empty and non-empty list in coq

Tags: coq

I'm new in Coq. How can I prove the disjunction of empty and non-empty list is true?

```
l = [] \/ l <> []
```

This is the lemma I'm working on:

```
Lemma in_list: forall (X : Type) (a : X) l (P : X -> Prop),
        (a :: l <> [] /\ exists b : X, In b (a :: l) -> P b) ->

  (P a /\ l = [] \/
P a /\ l <> [] \/ ~ P a /\ l <> [] /\ (exists b : X, In b l -> P b))
```

So for proving the lemma one way seems to be considering two cases:

```
if l = [] or l <> []
```

Then

```
if l = [], P a holds
```

and

```
if l <> [], ~ P a /\ l <> [] /\ (exists b : X, In b l -> P b) holds
```

I can prove the lemma this way but I don't know how to go this way. I have done something similar for Prop type (not a list) like this for Variable R of type Prop which considers two cases of True or False. I'm not sure if I can do something similar for list.

```
destruct (classic R) as [r | rn].
```

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the problem completely. I edited my question.

Comment: This `in_list` lemma doesn't seem to be provable. `if l = [], P a holds` is not provable because there is simply not enough information in the premisses (I mean `In x [a] -> P x` (for some `x`) doesn't seem to be useful when `x <> a`). Could you state the problem where `in_list` should be used?

Comment: In my assumption (exists ...) if the list l is [ ] then there has to be an element in list which must be 'a' that P a holds.

Comment: If you restated the assumption as `exists b : X, In b (a :: l) /\ P b` it would get you through the case `l = []`, but even that would be useless for the `cons` case.

Comment: Let me translate your original `exists b : X, In b (a :: l) -> P b` into English (for the case where `l = []`): there exists `b` such that *if* you can prove `b` is in `[a]`, then `P b` holds. Now, let's analyze if we can use it. If you have decidable equality over the list elements (of type `X`), then you have further two cases: (1) either `b = a`, which means we are done; or (2) `b <> a`, but this means you *cannot* construct the proof of `In b [a]`, so you cannot use the implication. And even if you *could* use it, you'd get `P b`, where `b <> a`, so it wouldn't get you `P a`.

Comment: So what does the exists mean there? doesn't it mean that there exists a b that is in [a]?

Comment: How do you write this in coq words? `If ( there exists a 'b' in l )` then `P b`.

Comment: You did this translation right. But the proposition you got is not strong enough to prove the lemma.

Comment: You can write it as answer so that I can choose it as best answer if you want.

Comment: Technically your question is about proving `l = [] \/ l <> []`, so Zimm i48 correctly suggested the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know about:

```
destruct (classic R) as [r | rn].
```

It can be used with any `R : Prop` and it relies internally on the excluded-middle axiom.

One simpler version exists where no axiom is needed because you already know that the object can be only of several forms:

```
destruct l.
```

where `l` is your list here, but it could be a natural number as well or a proof of a disjunction...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic question, which looks like question 1 of a home assignment, so I would advise you to:

- think about it on paper: how would you prove that with pen & paper ?
- what tactics do you know, which one could apply here ?
- as @anton said, at least explain us what you tried and what failed

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the problem completely. I edited my question.